# Pseudo-code for dequeue

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode, deque

*A queue is to be held in a linear array called Q with number of elements = limit (numbered 0 to limit-1). The oldest element of the queue is to be held in array element 0 (at the front), the next in array element 1, and so on. A variable back stores the index of the array element containing the newest element in the queue (or -1 for an empty queue).*

### How do i write 'size' operation (in pseudo-code)?

**

Comment: To the specification, yes. But a dequeue algorithm in O(n) is surely a bad idea.

Comment: you dont need the for loop if you implement a circular array ;)
see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) .

Comment: There is [codereview@stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of "questions". If You don't have an exact one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply decrement the index that contains the last element, and return that value. Next time you add something it will overwrite the actual value of the last element. The pseudocode is pretty simple then:

```
dequeue() { 
    returnValue = queue[index]; 
    queue.index = queue.index - 1; 
    return returnValue; 

}
```

IE. Your algorithm is very inefficent. The remove operation can be done in constant time (fast) as opposed to being linear with respect to the number of elements (slower).

Comment: RsinghS... could i return the size of array?? if you could help, i'll be grateful :)

Comment: Do you mean the number of elements or the total capacity of the queue? If it is the number of elements then you simply return the value of the index + 1. If it is the total capacity then whatever language you use will have the capabilities of giving you this value.

Comment: @Rsingh... yeah i've just found it's: return rear - front + 1; Which is probably equivalent to: return rear + 1;